# Is there a USB camera that works with linux with software-controllable white balance?

Tags: linux, webcam

I'm looking for a USB webcam for a computer vision application running on linux - and it has to be USB, firewire won't work in the particular application.

If I remember correctly the reason that this isn't possible with the USB cameras we've tested before (Quickcam 9000 Pro Rev.003), is that the driver does not respond to the API calls to control the white balance.

Has anyone got personal experience controlling the white-balance on USB webcams from linux, or know of a camera and driver combination where this is definitely possible?